# Hide address bar in mobile Chrome for non-scrollable page

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

According to Chrome docs, using:

```
window.scrollto(0,1);
```

can hide the address bar in Chrome for mobile. That, assuming that the page is taller than the viewport. In my case, I need to stick to a 100% x 100% size, so that trick won't work.

Are there any alternatives?